# Create nested Checkbox Dynamically with default value works fine on local but not on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

Hi there I am trying to create nested Checkbox Dynamically with default value and its works fine on my local system but not on server

HTML CODE

```
<div style="width:33%;float:left;"> 
    <span class="label">BodyParts/Muscles</span> 
    <div id="exerciseFilterList_1"></div> 
</div> 
<div style="width:33%;float:left;"> 
    <span class="label">Goals (Objective)</span> 
    <div id="exerciseFilterList_2"></div> 
</div> 
<div style="width:33%;float:left;"> 
    <span class="label">Device (Tools)</span> 
    <div id="exerciseFilterList_3"></div> 
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

JSCODE to fetch data and fill in checkbox

```
function getExerciseFilter() {
    $.getJSON("get_all_exercisefilter.php", function (dataAll) {
        $('#exerciseFilterList_1').html(dataAll.filter_bodyParts_view);
        $('#exerciseFilterList_2').html(dataAll.filter_goals_view);
        $('#exerciseFilterList_3').html(dataAll.filter_tools_view);
    });
}


/*----------
nested checkbox function*/

//nested checkbox function 
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
    console.log('always');
    var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
                  container = $(this).parent(),
                  siblings = container.siblings();

    container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        indeterminate: false,
        checked: checked
    });

    function checkSiblings(el) {
        var parent = el.parent().parent(),
                     all = true;
        el.siblings().each(function () {
            return all =  $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
        });
        if (all && checked) {
            parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                indeterminate: false,
                checked: checked
            });
            checkSiblings(parent);
        } 
        else if (all && !checked) {
            parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
            parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
            checkSiblings(parent);
         } 
         else {
             el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                 indeterminate: true,
                 checked: false
             });
         }
     }
     checkSiblings(container);
 });


/*----------
function that fetch data onload*/

function getEditData() {
    $.getJSON("get_exercise_by_id.php?cid=" + cid, function (data) {
        data = data[0];

        var myfilter = '';
        if (typeof (data.filters) != "undefined" && data.filters !== null) {
            myfilter = data.filters;
        }

        if (typeof (myfilter.body_parts) != "undefined" && myfilter.body_parts !== null) {
            var pharse_id = ''
            for (var body_parts = 0; body_parts < myfilter.body_parts.length; body_parts++) {
                pharse_id = '#filter_' + myfilter.body_parts[body_parts];
                $(pharse_id).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }

        if (typeof (myfilter.goals) != "undefined" && myfilter.goals !== null) {
            var pharse_id = ''
            for (var goals = 0; goals < myfilter.goals.length; goals++) {
                pharse_id = '#filter_' + myfilter.goals[goals];
                $('#filter_' + myfilter.goals[goals]).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }

        if (typeof (myfilter.tools) != "undefined" && myfilter.tools !== null) {
            var pharse_id = ''
            for (var tools = 0; tools < myfilter.tools.length; tools++) {
                pharse_id = '#filter_' + myfilter.tools[tools];
                $('#filter_' + myfilter.tools[tools]).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }
    }
```

data in json coming in this form:

```
[
    {
        "filters": {
            "body_parts": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "5",
                "6",
                "7",
                "8",
                "9",
                "10",
                "11",
                "12",
                "13",
                "14",
                "98",
                "99",
                "100",
                "111",
                "112",
                "113"
            ],
            "goals": [
                "120",
                "121",
                "122"
            ],
            "tools": [
                "133",
                "134",
                "135"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I have generated checkbox dynamically which works fine but when I fill data in checkbox on load its not working.Everything works fine on local but on server checkbox not checked onload of `getEditdata` function.

Below are the images of local and server

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, same code but not works on server. Even in console there is no js error.